# Powerapps Office365Users.UserPhoto failed

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerapps

Making a Powerapps Leave Request app. I can get all user and manager info, but when I try to obtain a user or manager photo, I get this error:

```
Office365Users.UserPhoto failed: { 
    "status":404, 
    "message": "No user found with the specified id...." 
    ...
    "source": "office365users-eus.azconn-eus.p.azukrewebsites.net" 
}
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Better wiki syntax formatting

Answer (score 1):

Here's the troubleshooting strategies I'd take to resolve your issue:

Find out what User().Email is actually showing--insert a label and set it to that expression.

```
User().Email
```

Manually type in the expected email address into Office365Users.UserPhoto function. What comes out?

```
Office365Users.UserPhoto("name@email.com")
```

Try the V2 version of the function and see the difference:

```
Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(User().Email)
```

Alternatively, collect User().Email to a variable:

```
Set(userEmail, User().Email)
```

Then reference the variable instead of the User().Email function:

```
Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(userEmail)
```

Let me know if that is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Dang, but no joy with any of those options:
Trying: Office365Users.UserPhoto("name@email.com")
Result: Same error

Trying: Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(User().Email)
Result: “ErrorItemNotFound,” “message”: “The Photo wasn’t found.” “innerError”:

Trying: Set(userEmail, User().Email), Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(userEmail)
Result: The method ‘UserPhotoV2’ has an invalid value for parameter ‘id’

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the connection to Azure AD, but only with the photo. Also, the photos do appear in the upper right corner (logged on user icon) when I and other users are logged into this Leave Request app.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the id that you get on the `MyProfile` (or `MyProfileV2`) function of the Office365Users connector:

```
Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(Office365Users.MyProfileV2().id)
```

Since the id came from the same connector of the `UserPhotoV2` operation, you should not have the error that the id was not found.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
If(!IsBlank(ThisItem.userprincipalname),Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(ThisItem.userprincipalname),SampleImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of options:

```
IfError(Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(User().Email),"")
```

Alternatively, you can check to see if a user has an photo;

```
If(Office365Users.UserPhotoMetadata(User().Email).HasPhoto,Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(User().Email),"")
```

I like to use the Person Icon to display if no image is found in the `UserPhotoMetadata`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `User().Image`? This is what I used in my PowerApps and it just worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(User().Email) , this worked for me